# How to make numbers show as dollar amount in formattable tables with colored bar

Tags: r, format, currency, formattable

So I am trying to make one of those cool tables where a numeric value will show up as a colored bar along with the numbers as text inside the formattable tables. 
I have sales number that are in whole numbers, and I know I can use the `currency()` function to change them into currency format without losing them as numeric values. However, once I added in the `normalize_bar` function, the numbers show up not as currency format anymore. Could someone tell me how to format that correctly?

```
prod$Sales<-currency(prod$Sales,digits=0L)
table<-formattable(prod, list(
area(col=Sales)~normalize_bar("green",0.2)
))
```

The result looks like this.

[Table with bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsiIK.png)

I know the format of the sales number has been changed to currency though (see the table without area below). But how I can make the numbers show up right?
[Table without bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdjtb.png)

Comment: It looks like use of `area` causes loss of formatting (https://github.com/renkun-ken/formattable/issues/96) - if you use `Sales = normalize_bar("green", .2)` it will work, but perhaps that's not what you need. Using v.2.0.1 I was not able to reproduce other examples with the same problem: https://www.displayr.com/formattable/ --- wish I could be of more help...

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own functions to format formattable output. Here, I show an example where the default output is currency with and without a normalize bar.

```
currencyout <- function(fun="currency"){
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  formatter("span", x ~ fun(x, digits = 2))
}
currencybarout <- function(color = "violet", fun = "currency") {
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  formatter("span", x ~ fun(x, digits = 2),
            style = function(y) style(
              display = "inline-block",
              direction = "rtl",
              "border-radius" = "4px",
              "padding-right" = "2px",
              "background-color" = csscolor(color),
              width = percent(proportion(as.numeric(y), na.rm = TRUE))
            )
  )
}
```

You can implement this, for example in data frame `df` for all columns after the first one (which I assume is a description)

```
formattable(df,
            list(area(col = 2:ncol(df)) ~ currencyout())
                 )
formattable(df,
            list(area(col = 2:ncol(df)) ~ currencybarout())
                 )
```

Comment: could the normalisation be on a column-by-column basis? Using your code, it appears to normalise over the entire table

Comment: Sorry for late response @MathewVickers - yes, you can do it by each one, but then you don't want to use the area feature. You want to do each one.